# Invoking command history from a Java program

Tags: java

We are trying to invoke Linux command `history` from a Java program.  We are able to invoke quite a few commands from Java, including `date` and `ls -l` without any issues.  However, `history` is failing with the `java.io.IOException`.  The sample source code follows:

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class OSCommand {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        dumpCommandOutput("Date", new String[] {"date"});
        // SUCCEEDS

        dumpCommandOutput("Long Directory Listing", new String[] {"ls", "-l"});
        // SUCCEEDS

        dumpCommandOutput("Command History", new String[] {"history"});
        // FAILS
    }

    protected static void dumpCommandOutput(String label, String[] cmdWithArgs) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Attempting to execute: " + label);
        
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdWithArgs);

        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        
        String str;
        
        while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }
}
```

---

**Exception thrown**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "history": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:621)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:486)
        at OSCommand.dumpCommandOutput(OSCommand.java:16)
        at OSCommand.main(OSCommand.java:10)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 4 more
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message you get from the exception as well as the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `history` is not a stand-alone program at all, but instead it's a command that your shell can execute. Just like `cd`, `fg` and `bg` are shell commands and can't be found as stand-alone executables.

Answer (score 0):

The command "history" is not an installed program in your linux distribution. Instead it is a build-in command available from the shell you are using. Therefore, there is nothing for java to execute with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. Check the results you get when you use the `which` command on the arguments for `date`, `ls` and `history`:

```
linryzen ~ # echo $0
bash
linryzen ~ # which ls
/bin/ls
linryzen ~ # which date
/bin/date
linryzen ~ # which history
which: no history in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:
                      /opt/bin:/usr/lib/llvm/12/bin:/usr/lib/llvm/11/bin:
                      /usr/lib/llvm/9/bin)
linryzen ~ #
```